# Java calling unknown code or method from, not yet, existing dependency

Tags: java, dependency-injection, compilation

i have two independent projects Basic and Extension with following setup

Project A:

```
class Handler {
    public void handle(){
        ...
    }    
}
```

Project B

```
import Handler; //from Proejct A

class SomeClass{
    someMethod() {
        handle(); //dependency to Project As class with handle method
    }
}
```

So the problem is the dependecy to the handle method which exists at Project A but not at compile time on Project B.

The final step is to have build Project Extension as a jar and import it inside Project Basic.

Ofc the compiler will give me error when i build Project B since the handle is not known at compile time.

For this issue i need a solution:

Either: Tell java that the missing code (import class with handle method) will be there at running time.

Or maybe Dependency Injection due to a factory pattern.
I am known to the factory pattern, but i don't understand how it could help me in this situation.

Or another solution.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither of these are valid Java - won't compile.  The proper keyword is "class", not "Class".

You *have* to provide it at compile time once you get it right - you have no choice.  No way around it.

Maybe you should look at the Java JDK and follow the [example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/package-summary.html) in the `java.sql` package: Interfaces.  `Connection`, `ResultSet`, `Statement`, etc. are all interfaces so vendors can provide their own implementations.  Users only deal with interfaces.

Your `GenericHandler` should be an interface that you provide to clients.  They add their implementations and add their JAR file containing the custom implementation at runtime.

Basic interface that all extensions implement:

```
public interface GenericHandler {
    void genericHandle();
}
```

Extension code:

```
import GenericHandler;

public class Extension implements GenericHandler {
    public void genericHandle() { 
        // Do something useful here
    }
}
```

The factory pattern works *only* if you provide a finite, closed set of implementations:

```
public class GenericHandlerFactory {
    private final GenericHandlerFactory instance = new GenericHandlerFactory();

    private GenericHandlerFactory() {}

    public GenericHandler getInstance() { return this.instance; }

    public GenericHandler createHandler(Class genericHandlerClass) {
        GenericHandler result = null;
        // Code to create the GenericHandler you want.
        return result;
    }    
}
```

If users can extend your interface without your knowledge then a factory can't work; you have to stick to the JDBC example.

Comment: "No way around it." - this is not true. You can use reflection to call code which does not exist at compile time. But of course, this is only a way to follow if there is no other way and you know what you are doing and why ...

Comment: I'll cite the JDBC example: No reflection there.  I think something simpler, without reflection, is a better solution.

Comment: Like i said about the factory pattern, What i dont understand is, which parts have to present in which Project.

Comment: You spell out the interface; users provide the implementation.  The last piece is some kind of interface injection to let users say "Use my implementation."

Comment: Sorry maybe i was a bit missleading with my description. The extension  (now SomeClass) class has nothing to do with the "extend" keyword. I only wanted to say: i have a seperate project with a dependency to a  method from another project, It could be a class variable inside the extension class i.e. The handler has not even to be generic. I only need to call one method from Project A (Basic). (I changed names to Project A and Project B)

Comment: My answer still stands.